# how to create Exception class in salesforce?

Tags: apex, exception

> i am unable to create Exception Class with postfix name Exception..
>   how i create that class
>   [image]

Answer (score 4):

As the error message suggests, your class must also extend another Exception class such as `Exception` itself:

```
public class abException extends Exception {
}
```

See e.g. [Creating Custom Exceptions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apex_workbook.meta/apex_workbook/apex7_5.htm).

Comment: this error will come when i create new Apex class with name abException

Comment: @NamanArora Best you add exactly the code that fails to your question - custom exceptions are widely used and can be defined.

Comment: this will  just come when i create new Apex class. salesforce-->File->new->Apex Class->the class name like abException,,the error will come.

Comment: @NamanArora I've just cut and pasted the code in my answer and used Setup -> Develop -> Apex Classes -> New then Save to successfully create the class. Follow the same steps.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CalculationException extends Exception{}
```

Supported Constructors

1. `new CalculationException();`
2. `new CalculationException('This is bad');`
3. `new CalculationException(e);`
4. `new CalculationException('This is bad', e);`

Throwing exception

`throw new CalculationException('Your custom message', e);`

This class has all the methods of Exception class.
For more details check [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apex_workbook.meta/apex_workbook/apex7_5.htm)

Comment: @Naman I think you haven't added ' extends Exception' at the end of the defination like 'public class AException extends Exception {}', try adding that if you haven't